is there any inconsistancy if i claim thing-in-itselmselves are giving our mind "causality"?
i'm simply testing this out
the "problem of affection" in kant happens because kant says causality is an apriori knowledge
can't we just say, thing-in-itself gives us "causality" in our mind, because "causality" is a property of thing-in-itself, itself?
so unlike kant, we simply say thing-in-themselves can be known to some extend, and causality is not just some knowledge in our mind, but it's a fact of both noumenal world and phenomena
because as far as i know, kant never explains the origin of categories of pure understanding
so causality is a truth of this world
our perceptions are still unreliable because the "sense-data" we get might get altered by other categories of pure understandings that are not guaranteed to represent the noumenal world
edit: definition of thing-in-themselves is "things as they are outside of our mind"

"Causality" we use in our mind operates in space and time. Even if we analogize it to some 'logical' sense that can be applied to things in themselves, this analog will have a distinct meaning. "We simply say...  it's a fact of both noumenal world and phenomena" is just equivocation. Categories of pure understanding do not represent the noumenal world, nor can they or are  meant to. Attempting to use them that way leads to inconsistencies of the  "transcendental illusion".

@Conifold i'm not trying to interpret kant here, i'm suggesting a new system that is not kantian anymore, i know kant says "Causality" works in space and time, i'm saying what problems would it cause if we claim it also operates outside of mind too? so for example, let's assume materialism is true, when we dream we are creating a world with our minds and the world outside of dream is a real world as it is in-itself, both in "outside world" and in dream, causality functions, in dream it is an "apriori knowledge" that structures our world but outside of dream it is a feature of the world

@Conifold in this context i would say Thing-in-themselves definition is "things as they are outside of our mind", kant says thing-in-themselves are not in space and time but this assertion is unjustified how can kant know this? he doesn't know how the world is outside of his mind so he can't claim it's not in space or time

He argues previously that space and time are forms of our intuition and it makes little sense for things in themselves to conform to us. This more general point is independent of his specific views about space and time. Why should any conception we use to organize our experience, like causation or space and time, apply to things as they are? If we are keeping his idea of things in themselves that is non-sensical, this is how we know. And if you want a non-Kant's epistemology, why keep things in themselves at all and not discard them as Fichte, Hegel and neo-Kantians did?

@Conifold "space and time are forms of our intuition and it makes little sense for things in themselves to conform to us." kant defined TIT as how things are in themselves independent of our perception of them, but to me this is an overreach to claim they can never be cognized, the reason i don't like abandoning it as later thinkers did is because i still find it appealing to use the term for things that are outside of our mind, is there any other philosopher that has a term for "things that are outside of our mind"? and this "thing" can have different rules than the rules inside the mind

"Things in themselves" is not a term for things outside of our mind, those are "objective" or "mind-independent" things that any metaphysical realist accepts. "Things in themselves" specifically refer to that intrinsic side of things that is incongruent with our cognitive apparatus and hence can never be cognized (by us) by definition. If you do not believe that such a side of things exists then you should simply drop the term to avoid confusion.

@Conifold thanks for clarification

There are many issues to debate here and apparently Parsa Fakhar disagrees with Kant on some fundamental points in the enlightened dialog with Conifold on the comments, despite his question being about Kant. I believe that each philosopher has to be understood with a system and with his convictions, so that the radical alteration of some fundamental concepts of Kant would lead to a totally different thought. We can study this thought separately, but we need to know more about it.
So, let's break down the answer. First, we will answer in the Kantian context, then we will problematize and talk a little about the proposed variant that, in my opinion, would have to adapt to Hume's arguments. Actully, I'll repropose the question in another terms, outside Kant's Philosophy, later.
Your question delves into a critical and complex aspect of Kant's philosophy, particularly his distinction between the noumenal and phenomenal realms and the role of the categories of understanding, such as causality. Let's break down your concerns and see if there is any inconsistency in claiming that things-in-themselves impart "causality" to our minds.
Thinking in purely Kantian terms

Phenomena and Noumena:

Phenomena: These are the things as they appear to us, structured by our sensory and cognitive faculties.
Noumena: These are things-in-themselves, which exist independently of our perceptions but are ultimately unknowable to us.


Causality as an A Priori Category:

For Kant, causality is an a priori category of the understanding. This means that it is a fundamental way in which the human mind structures experiences. Causality is not derived from experience; instead, it is a necessary condition for the possibility of experience.


Problem of Affection:

The "problem of affection" refers to the question of how things-in-themselves can affect our senses if we can never have direct knowledge of them. Kant posits that our sensory data are affected by the noumenal world but processed and structured by our a priori categories, such as causality.



Testing Your Claim
You suggest that things-in-themselves could be responsible for giving us the concept of causality, which implies that causality is a property of the noumenal world as well as the phenomenal world. Let's explore this in detail:

Consistency with Kant’s Framework:

A Priori Nature of Causality: If causality is a property of the noumenal world imparted to our minds, it would contradict Kant's claim that causality is an a priori category. Kant insists that causality is not derived from experience or from any interaction with things-in-themselves but is a necessary condition for making sense of experience.
Knowledge of Noumena: Asserting that we can know that causality is a property of things-in-themselves implies that we can know something about the noumenal world. This contradicts Kant's fundamental assertion that noumena are beyond our cognitive reach.


Origin of Categories:

Kant argues that the categories of understanding, including causality, are inherent structures of the mind. He does not attribute their origin to the noumenal world but rather to the nature of human cognition itself. The categories are part of the mind's constitution and necessary for organizing sensory data into coherent experiences.


Implications for Kant’s Philosophy:

Phenomenal vs. Noumenal: If causality were both a noumenal and phenomenal property, it would blur the clear distinction Kant maintains between the two realms. This distinction is crucial for his entire critical philosophy.
Cognitive Limits: By claiming we can know aspects of the noumenal world, you challenge the limits Kant places on human cognition. Kant’s philosophy aims to establish these limits to delineate the scope of human knowledge and avoid metaphysical speculation.



Alternative Perspectives

Post-Kantian Developments:

Some post-Kantian philosophers, like Fichte and Schelling, attempted to address the limitations Kant imposed by exploring ways to bridge the noumenal and phenomenal worlds. Hegel, in particular, sought to overcome this dualism through his dialectical method.


Phenomenology:

Later, phenomenologists like Husserl shifted focus from the noumenal/phenomenal distinction to the structures of experience itself, arguing for a more direct analysis of consciousness and intentionality.


Hume (My prefered one): I'll develope apart.


To address how the claim that "things-in-themselves can be known to some extent, and causality is not just some knowledge in our mind, but it's a fact of both the noumenal world and phenomena" might fit with Hume's philosophy, we need to compare and contrast Hume's and Kant's views on causality and knowledge of the external world. Let's break this down step by step.
Hume's Perspective on Causality and Knowledge

Empiricism:

Hume is an empiricist, meaning he believes that all knowledge originates from sensory experience. For Hume, there are no innate ideas or concepts; everything we know is derived from what we perceive through our senses.


Causality:

Hume famously argues that our idea of causality is not a rational, a priori concept but is instead based on habit or custom. We observe that certain events consistently follow others, and we come to expect the same pattern to hold in the future. This expectation is the basis of what we call causality.
According to Hume, causality is not something that we can observe directly; we never perceive the necessary connection between cause and effect. Instead, we infer causality from the constant conjunction of events (i.e., whenever A happens, B follows).


Skepticism about Knowledge of the External World:

Hume is skeptical about our ability to know anything beyond our immediate experiences. He argues that we cannot have certain knowledge of the external world or of the self as a persistent identity because such knowledge would require going beyond what we directly experience.



Comparing with Kant's Philosophy

Kant’s Response to Hume:

Kant's critical philosophy is, in part, a response to Hume's skepticism. Kant agrees with Hume that we cannot perceive the necessary connection in causality through sensory experience alone. However, Kant argues that causality (and other categories of understanding) is a necessary condition for the possibility of experience. We cannot have coherent experiences of a world without applying these a priori concepts.
For Kant, causality is an a priori category of the mind that structures our experiences, making empirical knowledge possible. This is a fundamental departure from Hume's view that causality is a posteriori and based on habit.


Noumenal vs. Phenomenal:

Kant introduces the distinction between the noumenal world (things-in-themselves) and the phenomenal world (things as they appear to us). According to Kant, we can never have direct knowledge of the noumenal world; we can only know things as they appear within the framework of our sensory and cognitive faculties.
Kant’s categories, including causality, apply only to the phenomenal world. The noumenal world remains beyond our cognitive reach, although it is posited as the ultimate reality that underlies appearances.



Your Claim: Integrating with Hume
If we propose that "things-in-themselves can be known to some extent, and causality is not just some knowledge in our mind, but it's a fact of both the noumenal world and phenomena," we are moving towards a position that seems to integrate elements of both Kant's and Hume's philosophies, but with significant modifications. Let’s see how this could fit:

Knowledge of Things-in-Themselves:

Partial Knowledge: If we assert that things-in-themselves can be known to some extent, we are stepping away from Kant's strict separation between noumena and phenomena. This view would need to allow for some direct or indirect access to the noumenal realm, which is contrary to Kant's assertion that such access is impossible.
Humean Influence: From a Humean perspective, acknowledging any form of knowledge about things-in-themselves would require a clear explanation of how such knowledge is empirically grounded, given Hume's skepticism about knowing anything beyond immediate experiences.


Causality as a Property of Noumenal and Phenomenal Worlds:

Consistency with Hume: Hume would reject the idea that causality is a property of the noumenal world since he denies the possibility of knowing necessary connections beyond habitual associations observed in experience.
Integrative Approach: To reconcile this with Hume, one might argue that the habitual patterns we observe (which Hume discusses) reflect some underlying reality, but this would be speculative from a Humean standpoint. In essence, this would be a significant departure from Hume's empiricism and skepticism.



Conclusion
On comments, Parsa Fakhar says that "Thing-in-themselves definition is "things as they are outside of our mind", kant says thing-in-themselves are not in space and time but this assertion is unjustified how can kant know this?".
Based on this, I would say he has empiricist scruples that Kant tramples over. Kant, in fact, introduces into philosophy the mysticism of human action, which is something that does not respond to natural laws. For people like me, who have spent their lives trying to create artificial intelligence, this is a serious flaw. Hume, then, would be the best alternative to sophisticated and modern empiricist thinking. But there are still many problems with this perspective, as Hume does not believe that one can "directly perceive" causality. I tend to agree with him, but I would need to know the position of the author of the question in relation to Hume.
The claim that "things-in-themselves can be known to some extent, and causality is not just some knowledge in our mind, but it's a fact of both the noumenal world and phenomena" poses significant challenges for both Kantian and Humean frameworks:

Kant: This view contradicts Kant's strict separation of noumenal and phenomenal realms and his insistence that causality is an a priori category of the mind applicable only to phenomena.
Hume: This view goes beyond Hume's empirical skepticism by suggesting that causality is an inherent property of reality itself, rather than a habit of thought based on observed regularities.

Reconciling this view with Hume would require a substantial departure from his empiricist and skeptical principles, potentially adopting a more realist or speculative metaphysical stance, which neither Hume nor Kant would fully endorse in their original forms. Therefore, while an interesting proposition, it challenges the core tenets of both philosophies and would require a new framework to fully integrate these ideas.

+1 for a superb answer! Clear, informative, well written, puts all mine to shame. I don't understand why it hasn't had more votes.

Your hypothesis is based on the lack of a clear set of arguments for the origin of categories, so you assume that "the thing itself endows our brain with causal relationships", which is somewhat similar to breaking out of the epistemological framework and attempting to explain the origin of categories from a materialist perspective using the theory of "matter determines consciousness".
Kant has never explained the origin of categories, and I don't think it's because he doesn't know the meaning of this thing or he disdains doing it. It can only be said that this is a very difficult thing. But explaining the origin of categories is indeed a very important thing, and when I was studying Kantian philosophy, the first question that came to my mind was this. For this reason, I spent a considerable amount of time contemplating this issue.
I want to use a purely spiritual approach to explain the origin of categories, which is completely different from your idea of using materialist theory to explain the origin of categories. This text is quite long and was written about two years ago. It may not be professional, but I hope it can be helpful to you.
Kant fully demonstrated how our brain processes the information projected from the objective world onto our senses into knowledge, allowing us to clearly understand how humans use categories to understand the world and how knowledge is generated. Similarly, with the help of Kant's category theory, we can also explain many cultural issues that we find difficult to understand.
For example, the dragon is a symbol of evil in Europe, while in China it is a symbol of auspiciousness. Religion is the spiritual sustenance of people in Europe, while in China it is something that confuses people, and so on. These are all due to people from different places, with different categories and paths. Over time, even the descendants of modern Homo sapiens of the same lineage and origin have formed many different understandings of the phenomena in this world due to category reasons.
Based on the above example, we can say that categories have a natural barrier to human communication. How did humans break through these barriers for communication and integration? I think what helps humanity break free from category constraints is definition. I believe that definition is a bridge between categories and rationality that have not yet been fully understood and studied, and it is the key advancement of categories.
I believe that when we understand this objective world, due to differences in our perceptual abilities, there are many innate differences in our respective experiences. If there is no definition, categories cannot be unified, experience cannot be exchanged, and knowledge cannot be formed.
We often see the phenomenon that if two people happen to have an anonymous discussion on a science and technology forum, they may become good friends after a heated argument. But if they happen to have another anonymous discussion on another social and cultural forum, they may curse each other and see each other as unreasonable people due to some minor differences.
In fact, this phenomenon is actually very common. Why do we almost never have differences in value orientation when discussing scientific and technological issues, but there is always an insurmountable ideological gap when it comes to social and cultural issues?
I think the reason may not only be whether the viewpoint can be verified. Because social and cultural issues can also be verified, why can't we also maintain a neutral and objective attitude on these issues? Science and technology also have countless mysteries to be solved, why can we objectively and rationally view them?
The answer is that we have overlooked the significance of the definition.
The definition referred to here not only refers to precise regulations and connotations, but also includes general conceptual portraits. In fact, all the things we define have undergone changes in their provisions and connotations, or are all uncertain, even in science. The definition of the same thing in human society has always been vastly different.
Putting aside the concept of social culture, let's not talk about it. Taking science as an example, in astronomy, the number of planets in the solar system used to be eight, later changed to nine, and now it has been changed back to eight. The reason is that astronomy has continuously gained new understanding of planets during its development over the years. Although the operational patterns and essence of these planets, whether they are eight or nine, have not been affected in the slightest, they have an obvious guiding role for us to further understand them.
This matter has not caused as much controversy as general social and cultural issues, and no one has accused it of violating tradition and principles, or any conflicting interests. The reason is that astronomers initially relied on definitions to work, which accelerated the speed at which astronomers reached consensus and also resolved the inherent contradictions caused by differences in experience.
It can also be said that the key to understanding this objective world is not based on what we observe, but on what direction of inspiration we can obtain from the surface of these objective worlds. The so-called limitation of reason is essentially the loss of direction in understanding. And it is the inherent deficiency of categories that causes this kind of loss phenomenon.
According to Kant's definition, category is the rule followed by our brain's cognitive ability in the comprehensive processing of observed phenomena. Although in the context of Kantian philosophy, the comprehensive processing ability possessed by the human brain is a subjective prior. But I don't think so.
I believe that since it is a rule, it must not be natural, but shaped by nurture. How were these acquired rules shaped?
I think this starts with the history of modern Homo sapiens migrating from East Africa to the world 70000 years ago.
70000 years ago, Neanderthals began to be gradually expelled from the stage of history by modern Homo sapiens who had left East Africa. The most important reason for this was that their team size was very small. Compared to modern Homo sapiens, although they are stronger and have a larger brain capacity, they do not have the ability to form fictional stories. Because there is no division of roles, once we leave each other's sight, we cannot communicate and collaborate. Modern Homo sapiens, on the other hand, condense into larger teams through stories. Even if they are far from each other's perspectives, they are able to remember their tasks through character division, thus achieving division and encirclement of the Neanderthals.
But one thing is often overlooked: although modern Homo sapiens were able to form large-scale teams and conquer the entire world 70000 years ago, it was not until about 10000 years ago that human society began to settle and build cities, burn pottery, and develop agricultural civilization. During this period, modern Homo sapiens spent at least 60000 years in an uncivilized state with a large organizational scale but no knowledge. In other words, although modern Homo sapiens formed large-scale organizations 70000 years ago, they were not able to integrate appearances into knowledge, so they were just a group of organized but uninformed wild apes. There is still a crucial leap from the definition of human beings measured by the scale of civilization.
The 60000 year knowledge gap indicates that the formation of knowledge after organization is related to the organization. Regarding this point, we can look for clues from some ancient hieroglyphs. For example, in Chinese characters, the characters "文" and "交" have been like this from beginning to end. However, "文" and "交" respectively represent culture and communication, indicating that when Chinese ancestors invented writing, they fully realized that the so-called culture itself was born in communication between people.Not only are these two characters almost identical in writing, but their shapes are also presented in a straightforward cross, clearly expressing the definition of culture.
So, we can infer that civilization is gradually built through 60000 years of communication and integration between people under the influence of organizations.
But here's a question: why did all races, including Neanderthals, fail to form a category of communication and integration in the 3 million year history before modern Homo sapiens? And modern Homo sapiens only took 60000 years to form? There may be two reasons, one is that modern Homo sapiens have a sense of role, and the other is that their organizational scale is larger.
Although I have always disliked the notion that organizations shape human nature, it doesn't seem entirely unreasonable now. If it is assumed that organizations give birth to innate categories of people, many issues may be much easier to explain.
Firstly, from the perspective of Kantian philosophy, the human brain cannot form categories without reason. Kant believed that experience is not intuitive, and what our senses can truly perceive (also known as pure intuition) is only space and time.
Like other animals, the sensory information received by our brains is actually a jumble of disordered images and other intuitive information, including sound and temperature. When understanding actively synthesizes appearances, including grasping, reproducing, classifying, marking, etc., it is all the result of people's cooperation with each other. In fact, these behaviors are only necessary after individuals have taken on a role. It is difficult for us to imagine the significance and necessity of integrating these appearances as individuals without collective willingness and communication needs.
Secondly, why does it take humans as long as 60000 years to develop the ability to synthesize intellectual representations? Or rather, why did humans only take 60000 years to develop this ability? The answer to these two questions is the same, that is, this ability is a result of training, not an innate prior. And human self-awareness is gradually emerging from the previously established stream of consciousness in our brain during this long period of time (which can also be said to be brief for the entire history of life) by synthesizing appearances into orderly experiences and knowledge.
That is to say, all animal brains have a stream of consciousness in the context of Hume's philosophy, but modern Homo sapiens, due to the needs of characters and stories, when our brain comprehensively processes external images projected in, it causes the stream of consciousness in the brain to shift. This turn is not a change of direction in the geometric context, but an additional task has been added. This task is the act of modern Homo sapiens, inspired by character consciousness, virtualizing appearances into objective characters, also known as empathy.
However, it should be clarified that although organizations can promote the comprehensive representation of human intelligence, not all organizations have this function. For example, ants, although they have organization, they do not have a brain and innate intellectual abilities. However, gorillas, Neanderthals, and others, although they have brains, do not yet have the ability to form fictional stories like modern Homo sapiens, so there is no division of roles and the organizational scale is too small. The key to the uniqueness of modern Homo sapiens organizations lies in the fact that within this organization, individuals have awakened as story characters, resulting in larger organizational scales and wider communication. So modern Homo sapiens were able to break through the limitations of vision and sound to form large-scale collaboration beyond visual range and ultrasonic range.
If we distinguish organizations with story character characteristics like modern Homo sapiens from organizations of animals such as ants and gorillas, I think there is only one word that can accurately describe this difference, and that is "society.". That is to say, "society" is a narrative organization, and only when members unite through stories can such an organization be called society.
Although I acknowledge the role of organizations in shaping human nature, I still want to emphasize the individual's dominant position within the organization.
Because, just as ants and gorillas also have organization, as organizations of modern Homo sapiens, they themselves are not sufficient conditions for the birth of self-awareness and human nature. We may say that organization is one of the prerequisites for human nature, but if modern Homo sapiens do not awaken as story characters, then our organization is no different from the organizations of other animals. We may also be able to rely on such organizations for survival, but civilization can never be born.
If we acknowledge that the human brain cannot form categories without organization, then we naturally face an important question: for organizations, what is the first step in knowledge dissemination or the reason for knowledge accumulation?
I think the answer is the definition. If this critical link is not defined, people cannot exchange their experiences with each other. Of course, the experience here should not be seen as the experience formed by the comprehensive processing of knowledge in the context of Kantian philosophy, but as a pure survival experience that all living beings have the ability to summarize. It can also be called an unnamed experience that relies solely on genetic inheritance. The comprehensive processing methods such as reproduction, classification, and labeling must be based on or serve the definition.
Because our brains and senses only have consistent traits, but their abilities vary. Some people have good eyesight, some have a large brain capacity, some are particularly sensitive to certain things, and some are color blind. So, people's emotional abilities or the objective information they receive vary. If this critical step is not defined, even if we synthesize the external phenomena we perceive into experiences, we cannot communicate with each other through language because these experiences are inevitably different. For example, the experience of a visually impaired person is that attacking prey at a distance of 20 meters is the best position, but this is an ineffective experience for a visually impaired person.
We can even further infer that the time interval between the formation of society and the birth of knowledge and civilization is precisely delayed by the lack of defining ability. Because if experiences between people are communicated smoothly, knowledge is easily disseminated and accumulated. But in the early days, modern Homo sapiens did not have the ability to define and accurately understand the experiences transmitted by others, so civilization was only 60000 years later than society.
Of course, it can also be said that the reason why human society was able to give birth to civilization in just 60000 years is precisely because we have the ability to define and quickly improve the efficiency of experience dissemination.
In reality, animal intergenerational experiences can also be transmitted, but the vast majority are imitations rather than preaching, and some directly push their offspring into practice and provide guidance nearby. But animals do not have abstract language, so they cannot convert experience into abstract concepts, and cannot widely disseminate and preserve experience outside the brain in the form of knowledge like humans.
I think the reason why definition is so difficult is still due to the category. Although I do not agree with Kant's notion that categories are a priori ability, it is indeed difficult to explain how the human brain forms the ability for a priori perception. We can only say that after the awakening of role consciousness, the human brain is forced to turn in the organization (society). But this turn cannot be completed in a short period of time, and it can even be said that we have not yet completed it.
Before our brain was upgraded to its current state of intelligence, its operation was very mechanized. Simply put, there are only three steps to gather: case storage, model construction, and instruction transmission. This process is similar to the immune system in our body, relying entirely on the "exhaustive storage" and "traversal and backtracking" of virus information to complete. You may ask, what should I do when I am unable to exhaustively traverse? What should we do if there are new cases? The answer is death or being screened out. The model of "reproduction ->death ->mutation ->reproduction ->death ->mutation" in life against natural selection is itself a tragic epic and another grand and complex proposition.
So far, the human brain has not been fully developed, but has turned to be unfinished. I think the key to turning is to further enhance the ability to define.
Of course, I am not saying that all social and cultural issues should have clear definitions like science and technology. In fact, this cannot be achieved either.
But at least we should have a sense of definition when discussing these issues. With this definition of self-awareness, communication and discussion between people can be called rational. Otherwise, all debates can only be seen as emotional expressions manipulated by their own categories and limited experiences.
The above is my reflection on the question "How does category originate?" two years ago, but to be honest, I am not satisfied with my own set of arguments. Because the above text only deduces that definitions arise from organizations (society), but does not more accurately describe how people learn definitions from organizations (society). In the past six months, I have been trying to think about this issue in conjunction with the Younger Dryas incident, and have come up with some new ideas.
Let's first have a brief understanding of the Younger Dryas incident. Based on the general research findings, we can conclude that:

The Younger Dryas event is a typical non orbital event of sudden
cooling during the sustained warming process during the last glacial
period. It is of great significance for studying rapid changes in
ancient climate and environment, as well as short-term phenomena,
evaluating current climate and environmental conditions reasonably,
and making predictions about climate change. It is a global event
caused by a comet colliding with Earth, with a total period of
approximately 1100 years.
12900 years ago, the North American woolly mammoth, saber toothed
tiger, camel and sloth, and mountain lion suddenly became extinct, and
at the same time, the Clovis people also suddenly disappeared.
Afterwards, the Earth experienced a 1300 year long "spring cold
period" of intense cooling, known as the Younger Dryas period.
Researchers point out that nano diamonds need to be formed in the high
temperature and high pressure environment generated by the cosmic
explosion. Kenett said, "There is no other reason to explain the
appearance of these diamonds besides the power of outer space." He
believes that this comet impact on Earth is similar to the comet
impact that wiped out dinosaurs about 65 million years ago.
After the end of the Ice Age, the Earth's climate began to warm
approximately 17000 years ago, with temperatures gradually rising.
Glaciers in polar regions, North America, and Northern Europe began to
melt, and sea levels gradually rose. Grasslands in the Bohai Sea,
Yellow Sea, and Norwegian Sea were flooded. By 13000 years ago, a
significant portion of the ice and snow in North America and Northern
Europe had melted, and the warm spring flowers bloomed in the northern
and southern hemispheres, creating a prosperous scene. However, at
this time, 12640 years ago, temperatures suddenly dropped again,
causing severe cold in various parts of the world. Ice sheets in polar
regions, Alps, Qinghai Tibet Plateau, and other areas expanded, and
many animals and plants that had originally migrated to high latitudes
died in large numbers. This cooling is very sudden, and within just
ten years, the average temperature on Earth has dropped by about 7-8
℃. This cooling lasted for thousands of years, and it was not until
11500 years ago that the temperature suddenly rose again. This is the
famous Younger Dryas event in Earth's history.

The study of the Younger Dryas incident has shown that modern Homo sapiens may not be the main cause of the extinction of prehistoric large animals, in other words, the combat effectiveness of modern Homo sapiens may have always been exaggerated.
I believe that it is precisely because of the Younger Dryas incident that large-scale and rapid extinction of large animals occurred, and the food sources for modern Homo sapiens were greatly reduced, forcing them to start eating wild grains. This phenomenon is the direct and key factor that gave rise to agricultural civilization, rather than humans mastering agricultural technology at that time.
We can infer that modern Homo sapiens began to eat wild grains, and leftover or missed seeds were discarded next to caves, forming a certain planting experience over time. This is probably the earliest sprout of agricultural technology. As for why wheat, barley, and peas were first domesticated, it is clearly related to the growth cycle. The growth cycle of these three crops is only about 60-100 days, which can quickly fill people's stomachs and allow modern Homo sapiens to have a complete growth experience in temporary caves. However, other food crops have a longer growth cycle, and people are likely to migrate to other places before they mature. The earliest experience and knowledge of modern Homo sapiens may have been formed in this way.
We can continue to infer that the Younger Dryas event caused a global climate reversal of about 1100 years, during which many branches of modern Homo sapiens were trapped in small areas around the world due to heavy snow and ice, unable to achieve long-distance migration. This led to the emergence of the most primitive mountain worship and mythological legends in prehistoric times, as previous global migrations made it difficult for people to develop special emotions towards specific mountains, rivers, and streams.
So we can say that the Younger Dryas incident was a direct cause of the emergence of the earliest stage of human civilization, agricultural civilization. If it weren't for the Younger Dryas incident, could human civilization have been nurtured? This is likely a question that will always be answered. Because without the Younger Dryas incident, modern Homo sapiens would not have given up on meat and instead relied on staple foods such as wheat, barley, and peas. Moreover, without the Younger Dryas incident, modern Homo sapiens would not have settled in a place for a long time and would not have had emotional dependence on specific things. Perhaps it is at this stage that modern Homo sapiens, through collective planting activities and mountain worship, formed larger organizations and developed a sense of immersion in objective things, which is why humans have the motivation to name things.
Finally, we can conclude that it was during this stage of being trapped in various narrow areas that modern Homo sapiens learned to name things, as this is a collective memory that needs to be passed down from generation to generation. After the 1100 year long Younger Dryas incident 11500 years ago, modern Homo sapiens resumed long-distance migration. But by this time, modern Homo sapiens had mastered planting techniques, so they could survive in any place with fertile land even without large prey. More importantly, they had the earliest spiritual support and learned to name things. Although there is still a long way to go from defining concepts, being able to name different things is a leap forward. As people name more and more things, in order to distinguish and remember them, there is naturally a need to give unified connotations to similar things of the same kind. At this point, the complete category rules officially form a stable mechanism in human thinking. Categories may seem a priori, but if the above inference is correct, we can also say that categories, like other human abilities, have undergone a long evolutionary process. This process lasted approximately 8000 to 9000 years. As people's ability to define things grew stronger, around 800 BC, humans entered the Axis Age and began to attempt to define this world, questioning its essence.

Ok. Now we're getting somewhere! Wow.

Rereading further. It's kind of like: how can we pull ourselves from quicksand before the Munchausen Trilemma drags us to our deaths?

@Scott Rowe To be honest, I have written so much, but I don't think I have fully demonstrated the origin of categories, which is already a very difficult thing.
The only viewpoint that makes me feel very confident is that humans do not know when spiritual sustenance emerged, which is inevitably the starting point for modern Homo sapiens to name objective things: because they want to preserve this spiritual sustenance and pass it on from generation to generation.

@Scott Rowe From this perspective, the Younger Dryas incident is indeed the best explanation. Because at this stage, modern intelligent talents have the opportunity to stay in a place for a long time and gradually develop special emotions towards the local mountains and rivers over a period of 1100 years.
But there must be a prerequisite for this, which is that modern Homo sapiens at that time already possessed self-awareness and role division, and formed large-scale organizational capabilities.

@Scott Rowe But this raises a new question: when did the self-awareness of modern Homo sapiens awaken? When did you start having the ability to divide roles?
Regarding self-awareness and role division, the book Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind once mentioned that this was due to a genetic mutation, but so far, I have not seen any research on this genetic mutation anywhere

I admit that I can't fathom how variations in proteins can affect our cognitive abilities.

@Scott Rowe Yes, I can't understand either, but you have to admit the existence of that genetic mutation. Because before that, Neanderthals had better physical and brain capacity than modern Homo sapiens, and without a larger scale of organization, modern Homo sapiens could not have replaced Neanderthals. But without self-awareness and role division, the organization of modern Homo sapiens cannot break through the limitations of Rule Of 150.
So, the logic in Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind is valid, but currently no evidence has been found regarding that gene mutation.

Maybe we would have been better off with smarter Neanderthals. I have enough trouble with Rule Number 6, myself.

@Scott Rowe I don't think Neanderthals were smarter than modern Homo sapiens. Although they had a larger brain capacity, it was difficult for them to understand more complex things without upgrading their story characters. I even suspect that they may not have self-awareness.
BTW， What do you mean by Rule Number 6, is that it? https://www.rulenumbersix.ca/about/blog/rule-number-6/

Yes, that is the origin of the saying, and a good explanation about what it means. The Art of Possibility is very worth reading.

OP: can't we just say, thing-in-itself gives us "causality" in our mind, because "causality" is a property of thing-in-itself, itself?
This is what Heidegger draws together in The Principle of Reason, e.g.

"Only when we contemplated what λόγος meant for Heraclitus in early
Greek thinking did it become clear that this word simultaneously names
being and ground/reason, naming both in terms of their
belonging-together." (Page 112)

By 'being', in one form, Heidegger names it as the clearing – the illuminated open around Dasein from where phenomena appear.  So here, being, the clearing, is noumenon, thing-in-itself.

the clearing itself is being. Within the destiny of being in
metaphysics the clearing first affords a view by which what is present
comes into touch with the human being, who is present to it (GA9
Pathmarks, Letter on
“Humanism” (1946) p. 253)

Reason is the same as causality: the principle of reason, that nothing is without cause or reason.
In this answer the relevant type of causality and rationalisation are those used to result in Dasein, cogito or apperception, including all the underlying dependencies.
Part of the process of moving from being to cogito is rationalisation: the mind gathers itself through rationalising, albeit unconsciously.  Conversely the noumenon is a rationalisation from the evidence of phenomena, and vice versa because phenomena are rationalizations of perceptions (raw sensations from the clearing).
In gathering itself Dasein creates and depends on the groundless clearing, so the clearing is instrumental in the Dasein's unconscious rationalisation and gathering.
Kant's thing-in-itself is also an instrumental rationalisation, created to demark the subjective apprehension from the theoretical, inaccessible object.  It is slightly more specific than Heidegger's clearing but its relation to ratio/causality is quite similar.
Insofar as being, noumenon, and reason belong together there is therefore a close connection between "causality" and the thing-in-itself in that the latter is created and used instrumentally by the former in rationalisation.
It should be noted though, that in likening thing-in-itself to the clearing, as the clearing is being it has the characteristic that it is no thing.

'Being' cannot indeed be conceived as an entity; enti non additur
aliqua natura: nor can it acquire such a character as to have the
term "entity" applied to it. (Being & Time, H.
4)

Also in agreement with Nietzsche:

The thing-in-itself is nonsense. If I think all the "relations," all
the "qualities" all the "activities" of a thing, away, the thing
itself does not remain: for "thingness" was only invented fancifully
by us to meet certain logical needs—that is to say, for the purposes
of definition and comprehension (in order to correlate that multitude
of relations, qualities, and activities). (WtP
558)

